# How to downgrade oxygen-gtk

Tags: kubuntu, crash, oxygen

I have a problem with Eclipse, it crash every time I try to commit, or to view the project settings and I discover [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=178404) that the problem is for oxygen-gtk.

Is recommended to downgrade it. But how to? I have kubuntu 14.04.

Thanks.

Comment: First see the date of the question..

Comment: Yes, the title is different, but the problem and solution are same. Therefore it is a duplicate, although the other question is formulated better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to neatly downgrade a package in Ubuntu. However, in your case, you can just change GTK theme. `System Settings - Application Appearance - GTK` and change themes there. If it works, there are less ugly themes in separate packages, like QtCurve-GTK.

Comment: I had change other settings, thanks now don't crash!

Comment: "*There is no way to neatly downgrade a package in Ubuntu.*" You might want to make this more specific (or remove it if you think it's not important to your answer), because it's not true as you've said it. If the older version is still available through a configured software source, or you have the .deb file, you can just install the older version and that downgrades the package. (Downgrading Ubuntu from a later release to an earlier one is not supported, but downgrading individual packages within a release is supported and, at least in theory, should work as reliably as a package upgrade.)

Comment: You can not downgrade a library, because whole KDE (in this case) depends on exact new version. After Gentoo possibilities this seems completely unchangeable. Ok. In most cases, nearly always, it is not possible to downgrade a package in major number.

Comment: Use the keyboard if clicking on the Gtk2/Gtk3 drop-downs causes app to crash (as it did on my kunbuntu 14.04 system).  Use mouse to pick System Settings -> KDE System Settings -> Application Appearance;  GTK tab.  Then use tab or shift-tab to move the focus to the desired drop-down; hit up/down arrow to change themes AWAY FROM OXYGEN.